# Mostrar y ocultar un TextView por medio del mismo Botón

Tags: java, android

Intento hacer que el botón al presionarlo por primera vez me muestre un TextView y al presionarlo nuevamente oculte este mismo TextView...

```
btntv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De la siguiente manera puedes realizarlo usando el método `setVisibility()` pero usando `View.GONE` para esconder la vista:

```
btntv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            if(tv1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){ //si es Visible lo pones Gone
                  tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{ // si no es Visible, lo pones
                  tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, había pensado algo así con un if(), pero no sabía si era la manera correcta.